# Generating a complete superset?

Tags: javascript, combinations, permutation

Given the input string `NEIDESL`, I need to generate a superset of every combination of letters this string contains. I've tried a good few answers from StackOverflow.

However, upon executing with my input string, none of the results contain the word `DIESEL` which leads to me believe they are not complete supersets.

I'm using the follow snippet, found from [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/7025/110884):

```js
function strcombinations(str) {
    var fn = function(active, rest, a) {
        if (!active && !rest)
            return;
        if (!rest) {
            a.push(active);
        } else {
            fn(active + rest[0], rest.slice(1), a);
            fn(active, rest.slice(1), a);
        }
        return a;
    }
    return fn("", str, []);
}
```

I may be misunderstanding what a superset is here, any help appreciated :)

Cheers

Comment: If you're looking for *sets*, the order of letters doesn't matter.

Answer (score 0):

```js
//Lets Try this code.

const getAllSubsets =
  theArray => theArray.reduce(
    (subsets, value) => subsets.concat(
      subsets.map(set => [value, ...set])
    ), [
      []
    ]
  );

console.log(getAllSubsets(['N', 'E', 'I', 'D', 'E', 'S', 'L']));
```

Comment: `getAllSubsets(['N','E','I','D','E','S','L']).map(it => it.join("")).includes("DIESEL")` returns false

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).